# WordPress contact form 7 data validation

Tags: wordpress, validation, submit, registration

I've some students' roll and registration numbers saved in a txt/csv file. Now, I want, when any student want to register my WordPress website, his/her records will be checked, if matches, s/he will be able to submit for registration. Is there any solution of it in WordPress?

I am trying to register students if rolls and registrations are saved in the file/db